# How can I send args[2] and all args after it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

My current code has you use the command, mention the person you want to send it to, say how many times you want the message sent, and then the message. However, it will only send one argument when I do so. How can I make it send `args[2]` and all of the arguments that follow it?

Current code:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'attack',
    description: 'attack',
    execute(message, args) {
      
      let recipient = message.mentions.users.first();
  
      if (!args[2])
        return message.channel.send(
          'Please include the message you want to send.',
        );
      
      if (isNaN(args[1]))
        return message.channel.send(
          'Please include how many times you want the message to send.',
        );
  
      if (message.author.id === 'My ID') {
        for (let i = 0; i < args[1]; i++) {
          recipient.send(args[2]);
        }
      }
      
      if (!message.author.id === 'My ID') {
        message.channel.send('You do not have the authority to use this command.')
      }
    },
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can chop the first two items from the array using [`.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) and join the rest of them by space using [`.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).

You can run the snippet below to see how it works:

```js
const args = ['<@!322655127249097071>', '15', 'this', 'is', 'the', 'message']
const message = args.slice(2).join(' ')

console.log(message)
```

If you want to remove the first 2 items, you can use `.slice(2)`:

```js
if (message.author.id === 'My ID') {
  const messageToSend = args.slice(2).join(' ');

  for (let i = 0; i < args[1]; i++) {
    recipient.send(messageToSend);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first define a new variable to the name `message` or something. You can send this entire thing.

So most likely above your loop, you would define something like this.

```
if (message.author.id === 'My ID'){
       const message = args.slice(2).join(' ')
    
     for( let i = 0; i < args[1]; i++){
        recipient.send(message);
}
```

args.slice(2) will return a section of the string unmodified.
In this case, since you defined args it will return the second argument and onwards. Join puts spaces in between the arguments.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice

^recommend reading this for more.